# Modifying data member in loop of IList modifies other of elements of IList

Tags: c#, ilist

I'm very confused about this problem and not sure how to even title this question.

I've created an IList of one of my classes and then used .Add() to populate the IList. Once the IList is populated I need to iterate through the IList for a trivial check of some values and then set one of the data members of each element to 0.00.

The issue is that setting the data member of one element is also setting the same data member of the next elements. Here is an example of the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _ModelName;
    private double _Price;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    public string ModelName
    {
        get { return _ModelName; }
        set { _ModelName= value; }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _Price; }
        set { _Price = value; }
    }
}
```

I am using MyClass like this:

```
IList<MyClass> MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();

MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 1, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 119310.05 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 2, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 119310.05 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 3, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 119310.05 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 4, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 119310.05 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 5, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 6, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 7, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });

foreach( MyClass myclass in MyClasses )
{
    ... do something ...

    myclass.Price = 0.00;

    ... do something ...
}
```

Ok, the above code is an extremely simple representation of my actual code. What is happening is that when I set `myclass.Price = 0.00;` in the `foreach` loop all of the Price data members with matching ModelName are also getting changed to 0.00. So, in the foreach loop when I set the element with Id = 1 to Price = 0.00 I am immediately seeing this in the IList:

```
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 1, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 0.00 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 2, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 0.00 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 3, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 0.00 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 4, ModelName = "Model1", Price = 0.00 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 5, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 6, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });
MyClasses.Add( new MyClass { Id = 7, ModelName = "Model2", Price = 19810.32 });
```

I feel like this is a totally stupid question to be asking and I will probably end up finding an equally stupid reason for it happening. I've used F11 to step into every line of code involved and don't see anyplace where Price is getting set in other elements. For that matter, MyClass is completely braindead to the existence of it being contained in an IList.

It seems like this is being caused in the loop itself. I've also tried this approach with the same behavior:

```
for (int p = 0; p < MyClasses.Count; p++ )
{
    ... do something ...

    myclass[p].Price = 0.00;

    ... do something ...
}
```

I've added a watch:

```
MyClasses[p].Price
MyClasses[p + 1].Price
MyClasses[p + 2].Price
MyClasses[p + 3].Price
MyClasses[p + 4].Price
```

Stepping through the loop shows that when `MyClasses[p].Price` is set to 0.00 all of the other elements' Price member get set to 0.00.

Is there any possible explanation for this behavior other than there being something causing this in my class? Possibly something to do with an IList?

Comment: I'm not even referencing ModelName in the loop or in the class getter/setter for Price. I've traced through the entire loop with F11. All of the Price data members are getting set at the same time and on the same line (`myclass.Price = 0.00`) AFTER returning from the MyClass.Price setter. I honestly don't see how any of my code is doing this...

Comment: We can tell that you didn't post the actual code, because it's not possible to create a new instance of the interface IList<T>. I.e. "new IList<MyClass>" is illegal. The most obvious answer to your question is that you are actually copying the same reference to a single instance of MyClass for each unique ModelName value, so your list simply has that same instance in it multiple times. But without a proper concise-but-complete code example, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Also, note that when you update your post, you should simplify MyClass such that each property is just e.g. "public int Id { get; set; }". To ask a good question, you should make sure you are posting the shortest code that is readable and which demonstrates the problem. Explicitly-implemented properties doesn't do this.

Comment: Peter, you are right. I've corrected my example to create a new List. You are also right about the same instance scenario. I was not creating a new MyClass each time I did an Add(). There was a reason for that, but I have learned something over this hassle. I didn't know that the same instance would be treated as one. I change my code to instantiate a new MyClass for each Add() and it now appears to be working correctly. Thank you for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Good point on the brevity. ;) If you will create an actual answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious answer to your question is that you are actually copying the same reference to a single instance of MyClass for each unique ModelName value, so your list simply has that same instance in it multiple times. But without a proper concise-but-complete code example, it's impossible to say for sure.